# won't post in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

when i try to post a house instance it tells me the data is valid but won't save it knowing that it was working before i added the user attribute , the problem i think is in the "id" attribute

```
class houseSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = House
        fields =('id','user','title','city','type','address','rooms','beds','price')
```

the representation of the serializer

```
    >>> print(repr(serializer))
houseSerializers():
    id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
    user = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all())
    title = CharField(max_length=50)
    city = CharField(max_length=50)
    type = CharField(max_length=50)
    address = CharField(max_length=50)
    rooms = IntegerField()
    beds = IntegerField()
    price = IntegerField()
>>>
```

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def houseCreate(request):
        serializer = houseSerializers(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: `serializer.save()` instead of `serializer.save` ? (missiing paranthesis)

Comment: it's working now, thank you lool